# FQL - Dimensions for original high resolution Facebook images are sometimes incorrect

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, photos

Not sure if this is a bug, or I need to adjust my FQL query. Sometimes, the width & height dimension of the photo record is inaccurate.

From Facebook's [own example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/):

`SELECT pid FROM photo WHERE aid="20531316728_324257`

If I run

`SELECT pid, images FROM photo WHERE aid="20531316728_324257"`

On the first record, in the [0] position of images (the largest), I get

> {
>             "height": 1373, 
>             "width": 2048, 
>             "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/s2048x2048/168119_10150146071831729_5116892_n.jpg"
>           },

You'll notice that the image in the URL is not 2048x1373. However sometimes this *is* accurate, for other photos.

**How can I consistently retrieve the largest copy of a photo and its correct width & height?**

Answer (score 0):

> You'll notice that the image in the URL is not 2048x1373. However sometimes this is accurate, for other photos.

If the uploaded picture was smaller, then there is no image with these dimensions.

> How can I consistently retrieve the largest copy of a photo and its correct width & height?

You could ask for src_big_width and src_big_height from the same table, which in this case give the values 720 and 483 – and those are the biggest dimensions that this photo is available in.

But the docs say, these fields may be empty, so they might not be reliable in every case as well.

Comment: I've already tried using src_big, src_big_height, etc. But I want to use images[0] which is always the largest image they have (often larger than src_big). The issue is that on some records the size is accurate, and others its not and I dont want to use src_big.